# PDF-file gets big after processing

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a system that generates PDF-files using itextsharp and mails them to my users. And the files grows in a way that is not ok.

1. I start of with one 1 page word document 28 KB.
2. I print this one page word document using adobes printer and pdf file gets 73 KB.
3. I open the document in Adobe Acrobat X, insert my forms and save, 1055 KB.
4. I load the document in itextsharp and set the 30 different values and now my file is 2031 KB.

Is there any compression flags or tricks that can be set in itextsharp or in Adobe that keeps my file at ~73 KB. I don't add any images or any other media. just text.

BR
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar fun with PDF file size growing.  I've gotten form template generation down to a process where I get my template down to the smallest size possible before I send it to itextsharp to have it populate it.

In your step 3 you are adding your acrofields for your form.  After you've finished adding all your fields and saved the document, Used the "Reduce File Size..." option to help shrink the document a little bit. Then you can also use the PDF Optimizer to further reduce file size.  I personally use a work around when I use the Create PDF from multiple files feature, but only add the one document I'm working on and then select the smaller file size option for lower quality optimized PDFs.

Then in step 4 it depends on how you are populating and generating the PDF files. Our process uses the template PDFs generated and copies each page onto a new document with the form fields filled.  When copying instead of using the `PDFCopy` class we use the `PDFSmartCopy` class which will copy content to the new document, but will not duplicate content that is identical.  After switching to the smart copy class we saw a significant reduction in file size generated by itextsharp.

Hope this helps.